# Seedr package for R do not find the function physiodata

Tags: r, package, dataset

I am following the tutorial of seedr package, but following the instructions, it does not run. I am not sure if I am writing correctly or not.

I attach the example of the tutorial, and what I am writing.

The names of the dataset and columns fits with my code.

Not much different options I tried, only using different names for the data set and columns, but also i does not work.

[My example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccfr5.png)

Comment: did you do `library(seedr)` ?

Comment: ps please don't include [images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)